# Edited UITableViewCell is being stored as a new cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a table view that has a data source in sync with Core Data. However, I'm having a problem. Whenever I edit or delete a tableview cell, and I reload the view, I see a copy of the tableview cell that was there before it was edited. Here's some code to make it clearer.

When the view first loads, it tries to get all the "SOCommands" from "SOModule" which has a `one-to-many` relationship. Then, it converts it into "SOCommandTemp", so that I can work with them without altering the database.

```
_serverModuleCommands = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.serverModule.socommand allObjects]];
          for(int i=0;i<[_serverModuleCommands count];i++)
          {
               SOCommandTemp* newTemp = [[SOCommandTemp alloc]init];
               newTemp.commandName = ((SOCommand*)[_serverModuleCommands objectAtIndex:i]).commandName;
               newTemp.sshCommand =  ((SOCommand*)[_serverModuleCommands objectAtIndex:i]).sshCommand;
               [_serverModuleCommands replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newTemp];
          }
```

Then, when I'm editing cells, I call methods such as these:

```
[_serverModuleCommands addObject:commandValues]; //commandValues is in the form of SOCommandTemp

[_serverModuleCommands replaceObjectAtIndex:_selectedCommandCell.row withObject:commandValues]; //_selectedCommandCell is an ivar that is cleared immediately after use
```

Then, when saving, I convert the array into SOCommand by doing this:

```
for(int j=0; j<[_serverModuleCommands count]; j++){

                SOCommand* newCommand = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SOCommand" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
                newCommand.commandName = ((SOCommandTemp*)[_serverModuleCommands objectAtIndex:j]).commandName;
                newCommand.sshCommand =  ((SOCommandTemp*)[_serverModuleCommands objectAtIndex:j]).sshCommand;
                newCommand.somodule = newModule;                  
}
```

However, before this is called, I want to make sure that I'm saving only one array item, since I added and editing one cell, so I do this:

```
 NSLog(@"Going to Save: %@",[_serverModuleCommands description]);
```

And sure enough, I get only 1 array item. Then, I do save it, and exit the view controller. But when the first line:

```
_serverModuleCommands = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[self.serverModule.socommand allObjects]];
```

is called again, I'm getting two values in its description, one for the original and one for the edited.

Any help would be great!

~Carpetfizz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your saving segment, you create a new `SOCommand` object no matter if it already exist.

Why not just use the actual objects (`SOCommand`) and edit them, this will not alter your DB information until you save the context.
It will save you some grieve swapping back and forth between your objects.

If you cannot edit in context, you should pass the existing item `objectID` to your "temp" objects and if it exist, fetch this object from DB and make the update to the existing item:

```
NSManagedObjectID* oID = ((SOCommandTemp*)[_serverModuleCommands objectAtIndex:j]).objectID;
if(oID) {
    SOCommand* cmd = (SOCommand*)[context existingObjectWithID:oID error:nil];
    if (cmd) { //no error fetching the object
        //update `cmd` with your new values
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I replace existing ones?

Comment: Hello to you to @LeoNatan :D

Comment: Thanks, but SOCommandTemp* is just a normal NSObject, and doesn't have an ObjectID

Comment: Okay, yeah thanks I'll try it out. However, just editing the existing object sounds attractive too...

Comment: The only reason I had a temp was because I have a popover controller that sets the values to a command and returns the command, whether or not the command existed or not. So in order to set the commands, I had to initialize it like a ManagedObject, and that involved "adding" it

Comment: Changes to CoreData objects will not be committed until the contexts they were made on is saved to the store (hence no real point in creating temporary objects of your own). you might want to create another child context to your main and make your changes there so you might be able to discard them all if needed by deposing of the child context.

Comment: @DanShelly, sorry to bother you again, but I have a quick question, in the line where you say ` SOCommand* cmd = [context existingObjectWithID:oID error:nil];`, this doesn't work because it is returning an NSManagedObject and assigning it to an `SOCommand`. how do I get around this? Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Carpetfizz Your code describe `SOCommand` as a managed object subclass (it is inserted using an entity description and a context). you can cast it to `SOCommand` if you like. see my edit